# C# How to avoid splitting names in .Split()?

Tags: c#, regex, loops, foreach, split

So basically I have this loop where each sentence in *processedSentencesList* gets iterated and scanned for words which exist in the list *entityString*. And each entityString found in each sentence is added to *var valid_words*.

But the entities "Harry Potter" and "Ford Car" does not get added because of the 'sentence.Split()' statement.

How do I alter this code so that existing entities with spaces do not get separated in to two words?

```
    List <string> entityString = new List<string>();
        entityString.Add("Harry Potter"); //A name which i do not want to split
        entityString.Add("Ford Car"); //A name which i do not want to split
        entityString.Add("Broom");
        entityString.Add("Ronald");
        
        List <string> processedSentencesList = new List<string>();
        processedSentencesList.Add("Harry Potter is a wizard");
        processedSentencesList.Add("Ronald had a Broom and a Ford Car");
        
        
        foreach (string sentence in processedSentencesList)
          {
        
                var words = sentence.Split(" ".ToCharArray()); 
                   //But it splits the names as well
                var valid_words = words.Where(w => 
                   entityStrings.Any(en_li => en_li.Equals(w)));
                    //And therefore my names do not get added to the valid_words list
          }
```

**When printed, Output I get right now:**

> Broom
>
> Ronald

**Output I expect:**

> Harry Potter
>
> Ford Car
>
> Broom
>
> Ronald

Basically, the entities with spaces in between (2 or more words) gets separated and thus cannot be matched to existing entities. How do I fix this?

Comment: can you just search you sentence without splitting it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `foreach` with this :

```
List<String> valid_words = new List<String>();

foreach (string sentence in processedSentencesList)
{
    valid_words.AddRange(entityString.Where(en_li => sentence.Contains(en_li)));
}

valid_words = valid_words.Distinct().ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try matching instead of splitting.

```
[A-Z]\S+(?:\s+[A-Z]\S+)?
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/eF8fY4/8)

Comment: Nice! +1. It'd be nice to see it working in the context of OP's problem though.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through each item and use the 'String.Contains()' method, which will prevent you from having to split your search strings.

Example:

```
List<string> valid_words = new List<string>();

foreach (string sentence in processedSentencesList)
{
  foreach (string entity in entityString)
  {
    if (sentence.Contains(entity))
    {
      valid_words.Add(entity);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I see Xaruth's answer is more condenced and using .Distinct, might be faster to use his instead of two foreach loops.